# Build Pipeline does not show the console output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I setup a build pipeline. When I click on the console icon, it won't display the console output. It gives an error

> unable to resolve the server's DNS address

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Jenkins version 1.590 and build-pipeline-plugin version 1.4.4. I got it working by downgrading to build-pipeline-plugin version 1.4.2. There is an issue registered in the Jenkins issue tracker already:  https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25460

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the build pipeline plugin version 1.4.4,
I fixed this on my Jenkins server by
adding #main-panel {width:100%;} in JENKINS_HOME/plugins/build-pipeline/css/main.css